# How to use Profiler to profile a Start() function in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, profiling, game-development, profiler

When I use`Profiler.BeginSample("Update Example")` and `Profiler.EndSample()` in `Update()`, I can see **"Update Example"** in **Update.ScriptRunBehaviorUpdate** in the profiler window.

But when I use `Profiler..."Start Example"...` in `Start()`, I cannot see or find any mention in the profiler. Is there any way to track code in `Start()`?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Profiling;
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    BoxParameter bParameter;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Profiler.BeginSample("Start Example");
        bParameter = GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<ZombieInventory>().box;
        Debug.Log(bParameter.width);
        Profiler.EndSample();
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Profiler.BeginSample("Update Example");
        bParameter = GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<ZombieInventory>().box;
        Debug.Log(bParameter.width);
        Profiler.EndSample();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play with **Clear on Play** and **Deep Profile** turned on.

[image]

Moves to 1Frame after playback. It is easier to step using a controller.

[image]

Then you can check the following.

[image]

To see if you get a value, try searching for the script name in the search window. It will not give you the details, but you can check if the value is taken.

[image]

The following test code was used.

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Profiling;

public class ProfilingTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Profiler.BeginSample("Start Example");
        var list = new List<int>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 2000000; ++i)
        {
            list.Add(i);
        }
        Profiler.EndSample();
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Profiler.BeginSample("Update Example");
        var list = new List<int>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 2000000; ++i)
        {
            list.Add(i);
        }
        Profiler.EndSample();
    }
}
```

BTW: Maybe it is because it is test code, but the `Find` function is heavy and should not be used. caching `Camera.main` is the fastest way. the same goes for `GetComponent`.

```cs
Camera _camera;

void Start()
{
    _camera = Camera.main;
}
```